# Form with BOTH submit button and onClick for individual radio button progress updates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, radio-group

I have a questionnaire type form - a set of questions, each with a set of radio buttons to capture user responses.
Overall form is handled via
form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)"
with submit button.
Also each radio button has an onClick handler so I can report overall progress on the same page for the number of questions answered.

However the radio onClick is not firing the progressUpdate() handler.
Is it possible to embed onClick event handlers within a form?

This is part of a GAS application - any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: Could you provide the relevant parts of you code, both client- and server-side?